# convert ienumerable<string> to xpathnodeiterator

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, umbraco

i've had a look around, apologies if i've duplicated this question

i have a standard list
i.e.

```
List<String> WordsRequested = new List<String>();
```

I need to return an XPathNodeIterator of this list

What would be the most efficient way to perform this conversion?

E.G. in pseudo code

```
XMlDocument xd = new XmlDocument("<WordsRequested></WordsRequested>");
//imaginary method to add each string as a <Word/> Element
xd.Append(WordsRequested, "Word"); 
XPathNodeIterator xpni = xd.Select("//WordsRequest/Word");
return xpni;
```

I am returning this to an XSLTExtension in Umbraco

Comment: What's the problem with your suggested approach?

Comment: my problem with it is the imaginiary method doesn't exist and i am not sure what the most efficient one to use would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Umbraco, you can make use of the 'umbraco.library.Split' method. This will take a delimited string and return an XPathNodeIterator.

An example XSLT extension would be like this:

```
public static XPathNodeIterator GetWordsAsXml(List<string> words)
{
    return umbraco.library.Split(string.Join(",", words), ",");
}
```

Comment: aaah well that's very nice as I already have a delimited string :)